# Extjs Upload Excel File to WCF Restful service

Tags: wcf, web-services, excel, rest, extjs

i am trying to upload a file to wcf service and had it read the excel file and return me the data inside the file in json format. The had refer to the sencha example on how to create a file upload in estjs, the below is the code

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'fi-form',
    width: 500,
    frame: true,
    title: 'File Upload Form',
    bodyPadding: '10 10 0',

    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        labelWidth: 50
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name'
    },{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Select an Excel',
        fieldLabel: 'Excel',
        name: 'Excel-path',
        buttonText: '',
        buttonConfig: {
            iconCls: 'upload-icon'
        }
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function(){
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'rest/upload.svc',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
});
```

My questions is, in my wcf rest service what kind of data type will the service expecting?

In the client side code it is like posting the entire form back to the service, so can I use request.Form("Excel-path") to get the excel file?

Is this a good way to do it? I had tried to read the excel file in client side using

```
ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
```

but it only works in IE and it require to change some activeX settings in IE, that's why I'm considering using service to read the file instead. Would like to know is there any alternative way of doing it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS will create a hidden iFrame and POST the file to your server via a form in that iFrame.

Your server should have a URL that will accept a multi-part-form POST.

ExtJS expects an *HTML* response from your server.

Send to server:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data...
POST /files
Request Payload...
```

Server returns:

```
Status: 201 Created
Content-Type: text/html    
{
  success:true,
  id:123,
  link:"/files/123"
}
```

Your server should also have a controller that can return a representation of the file:

Send to server:

```
GET /files/123
Accept: application/json
```

Server returns:

```
Status: 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
{
  id:123,
  fileName:"somefile.xls",
  someData:"..."
}
```

So you need to do 2 things: POST the file to the server to get its link, and then GET the file from the server using the link.

Comment: Yes, Ext JS expects `text/html` as the response type. See [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload) for more info.